# Where do I find this article?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-vector-bundles

I have been searching for this paper for days, unfortunately I cannot find it.

Does any of you know how to find it?

Hirschowitz A. Problèmes de Brill–Noether en rang supérieur, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. I Math. 307 (1988), 153–156

Thank you a lot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Comptes Rendus de l'Académie des sciences numérisés sur le site de la Bibliothèque nationale de France [[source](https://www.academie-sciences.fr/en/Transmettre-les-connaissances/comptes-rendus-de-l-academie-des-sciences-numerisees-sur-le-site-de-la-bibliotheque-nationale-de-france.html)]

The paper is available at https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54949409/f19.image

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I think the French National Library has earlier issues of the journal, available here: https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&collapsing=disabled&query=%28dc.title%20all%20%22Comptes%20rendus%20de%20l%27Acad%C3%A9mie%20des%20sciences%22%29%20and%20arkPress%20all%20%22cb34394200t_date%22&rk=21459;2

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is available through the French National Library, here (page 153): https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54949409/f5.item